# Is this declaration `int fun-name(static int)` valid in C++ and why?

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

While programming in Turbo C++ I declared a function as following

```
int fun-name(static int)
```

then it raised an error `storage class static should not be defined`

Can someone help me in understanding it

Comment: No, it's not valid C++, which is why you get an error.

Comment: Stop using Turbo C++.

Comment: [Why not to use Turbo C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1961828/995714) Turbo C++ is not a C++ compiler because it's much older than the first C++ standard. That's why it doesn't have standard things like non .h headers (`iostream`), namespace...

Comment: It's allowed by the grammar but violates a semantic rule  [dcl.stc]/5 in C++14 ("There can be no `static` function declarations within a block, nor any `static` function parameters.")

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. I'm not even sure what the point is. There are 2 things wrong with this code:

You have a - in the name of the function. Thats a BIG no no.

Also, static pretty much means no matter how many objects of the class are created, there is only one copy of the static member.

Oh yes, and you don't name your "static int" type.

Something like this could be valid though:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    static int funName();
};
```

Comment: "static only works in classes" - that's really not the case, you can use static outside of a class.

Comment: fixed @Shiro basic stuff always gets me >:(